# Не выводится пагинация Wordpress. Где ошибка?

Tags: wordpress

Есть шаблон страницы, на которой нужно выводить посты из определенной рубрики.

Вот каким способом реализована:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Analytics page 
Template Post Type: page
*/ 
?>

<?php get_header('subsub'); ?>
<div id="analytics-post-section">
    <div class="content-container">


        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="analytics-page-title">
                        <h1><?php wp_title("", true); ?></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                    <?php
                        global $post;

                        $myposts = get_posts( 'numberposts=7&offset=1&category=1' );

                        foreach( $myposts as $post ){
                            setup_postdata( $post );
                            ?>
                                <div class="analytics-item">
                                    <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                    <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="analytics-link" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            <?php 
                                    }
                                    wp_reset_postdata();
                                    ?>    


               </div>

                            <div class="pagi-block">    
                                <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
                            </div>

                          <?php get_sidebar() ?>

            </div>  
        </div>


    </div>  
</div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Почему `<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>` не отрабатывает и не выводит пагинацию на странице?

Так же пробовал `<?php echo get the_posts_pagination(); ?>` - результат тот же.

Поиск юзал, но разобраться все равно не получилось :( help me.

Answer (score 1):

Данная функция работает с `global $wp_query`. Для кастомных запорсов используй `paginate_links` https://wp-kama.ru/function/paginate_links

Comment: Благодарю, получилось!

Comment: @Николай если проблема решилась - отметь ответ решеннием.